# Dynamics 365 CE transition rules vs. bulk edit

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Today I’ve realized that Dynamics 365 9.x status code transition rules does not work in case of using bulk edit form (tested on 2 different on-premise installations). Do you know is it a bug or a system feature ? I was not able to find any official documentation or Microsoft statement about it.

I’m just wondering is it “by design” system behavior or should it be reported to the Microsoft as a bug?

Comment: After more thinking about it I've realized that that behaviour could make sense. Becuase status codes on selected records before update could has a different values - there is no possiblity to apply single transition rule for every record. Unfortunately - there is no additional server side validation in that case (transitions rules seems to be working only client-side) so this situation requires writing custom validation code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a disclaimer from MS or discussion around community anywhere on internet, normally Bulk edit is limited like scripted fields cannot be bulk-edited. Not sure if this status reason transition validation is happening in UI layer or Server Business layer like OOB plugins. Also if there are multiple Status reason transitions available, it should popup a window to capture the "to be" status reason. How can it break? If the business logic is done only there in that popup screen, then Bulk-edit form may not have that logic built.

Btw, I will create a ticket to see their response as they can check in their own internal Known issue database or existing tickets repository for answering us. They can check with PG team to confirm us.

I see you posted in Dynamics community as well, someone may chime in hopefully. I tested this in CRM online v9.1 but after bulk edit I am getting error. So it works in a way.

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify how we're using it. We have a statuscode field visible on the form (which is presented as a normal optionset) with the possiblity of changing its value (we have many different statuses for Active and Inactive states). On the classic form - statuses prevented by the transision rules are hidden. In case of bulk edit form - all the statuses for the current state are available for selection which is not ok. I've also confirm the the same behaviour happens in the online version.

Comment: @PiotrGaszewski I tested with exact setup.. that’s why I said bulk edit form don’t have that logic built..

Comment: I'm just curious. Did you set up a ticket for MS? Get any answer?

Comment: @PiotrGaszewski I think I created but they asked for a support copy instance, between I got distracted in other work when the ticket is aged & archived :(

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment regarding all states showing up, I think that is by design.

The bulk edit form was(its pretty old) designed to allow users to edit all selected records regardless of the record state or the state of their individual attributes.

My guess is that the form was never intended to know the values of the selected records, and thus presents all available options in the optionset.

I've face other issues with the bulk edit form in the past and have created forms specific to bulk editing, which were set up higher in the form order, with limited security roles.  So only certain users would see those forms when bulk editing.

While that won't directly solve your issue, you could create "shadow" status fields which are meant only for bulk edits, which could call plugins or flows, handle the checks for correct status and make the updates.  Pretty janky though...